# How can I add a fonticon after an input field?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="site-title">Site title<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="site-title" name="" required> <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"><i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i></a>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a font-icon right after the input field but it is displayed below the input field currently.

How can I position it after the field?

Comment: by jQuery or Plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

> ```
> .input-container {
> display: -ms-flexbox;
> display: flex;
> width: 100%;
> margin-bottom: 15px;
> }
>
> .icon {
> padding: 10px;
> background: dodgerblue;
> color: white;
> min-width: 50px;
> text-align: center;
> }
>
> .input-field {
> width: 100%;
> padding: 10px;
> outline: none;
> }
> ```

Using CSS is much easier to align items on your page. 
Please see the W3Schools tutorial - it's simple and easily explained https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_form_icon.asp

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem i did this.i think you can use from flex in css and :after in css
 or you can use i tag in span tag and in div tag .if it doesn't work you can use from flex for icon and after in css.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="site-title">Site title<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="site-title" name="" required> <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"><div><span><i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i></span></div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow following example:

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="site-title">Site title<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> 
       <div class "form-input">    
         <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" id="site-title" name="" required> 
         <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
            <i class="mdi mdi-information-outline"></i>
         </a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

You can add following css:

```
.form-group {
  display: block;
}
.form-group:after,
.form-input:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  dispay: block;
}
.form-group label,
.form-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-group label span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.form-group .form-control {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
}
.form-group .form-control a {
 width: 15%;
 display: block;
 float: right;
}
```

If you are using bootstrap 4, its grid has been made up of flexbox. You can get complete guide on this link flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox